# Imap count all mails of email account

Tags: php, email, imap, php-imap

I'm trying to count all emails from and email but my script only count mails from inbox,

anyone know how to count all emails from the mail account including sent,spam,deleted, etc

```
$mailcnf = "mail.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert";
$conn_str = "{".$mailcnf."}INBOX";


$username = 'test3@sjnewman.co.uk';
$password = 'Woju6532';
$imap = imap_open($conn_str,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Server: ' . imap_last_error());

echo $message_count = imap_num_msg($imap);
```

Comment: I think the `INBOX` is the cause for being in the inbox. Take a look at http://www.electrictoolbox.com/open-mailbox-other-than-inbox-php-imap/.

Answer (score 0):

first use imap_list to list all available folders.
then $conn_str = "{".$mailcnf."}$mailbox"instead of mailbox
imap_num_msg should return the number of emails in the current mailbox

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each folder and use [imap_status()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-status.php) to count the number of emails in each folder. Here's an example:

```
<?php
$username = 'mail@example.com';
$password = 'password123';

// Define the connection string:
$server = '{server.example.net:993/ssl}';

// Connect to the server:
$connection = imap_open($server, $username, $password);

// List the mailboxes:
$mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server, '*');

// Loop through the mailboxes:
foreach($mailboxes as $mailbox) {
 $status = imap_status($connection, "$mailbox", SA_ALL);
    if ($status) {
      echo "Mailbox: $mailbox\t\tMessages: " . $status->messages . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "imap_status failed: " . imap_last_error() . "\n";
    }
}

// Close the connection:
imap_close($connection);
?>
```